# How do I tidy up my table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have the following table:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15580/

Which works just fine, but as soon as I enter a longer description in the 4th column, the buttons get messed up (they stack on top of each other).

I tried putting width and max-width to percentages:

```
<td style="max-width=10%">Winter</td>
<td style="max-width=10%">2014-12-01</td>
<td style="max-width=10%">2015-02-01</td>
<td style="max-width=40%">some text</td>
<td style="max-width=30%"><button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update</button><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</a></td>
```

But that had no effect. I just want the text in the description to wrap (I tried word wrap with no success also) within its boundaries and go down instead of spread and mess up the buttons.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT1** I should stress that this needs to remain scalable to some degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use css like this. To control your th with fixed `15%` width and the last one have `40%` width. Or you can just specific the percent you want of every column of your table.

```
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}
th {
  width:15%;
}
th:last-of-type {
  width:40%;
}
```

Comment: but then its not scalable? It will vary from screen to screen?

Comment: Well that is bad, I want it to be universal and independent from screen size

Comment: @Vrankela Sorry for my previous mistake. In fact you can control the width percent of table's column. And I update my answer. But infact the width control with percent of table is really really difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at following.
I have given a `td` fixed width and its wrapping.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15583/)

**HTML**

```
    <table class="table table-striped">


        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="panel-heading panel-heading-h2"><h4>Season name</h4></th>
                <th class="panel-heading panel-heading-h2"><h4>Season start date</h4></th>
                <th class="panel-heading panel-heading-h2"><h4>Season end date</h4></th>
                <th class="panel-heading panel-heading-h2"><h4>Description</h4></th>
                <th class="panel-heading panel-heading-h2"><h4>Action</h4></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Winter</td>
                <td>2014-12-01</td>
                <td>2015-02-01</td>
                <td>Small text</td>
                <td>


                    <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update</button>                  
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Delete</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>MidApril-EarlyJune</td>
                <td>2015-04-14</td>
                <td>2015-06-04</td>
                <td style=width:100px>Also small textAlso small texAlso small texAlso small textAlso small texAlso small texAlso small textAlso small texAlso small texAlso small textAlso small texAlso small tex</td>
                <td>


                    <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update</button>                  
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Delete</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>May-July</td>
                <td>2015-05-11</td>
                <td>2015-07-14</td>
                <td>Short text</td>
                <td>


                    <button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Update</button>                  
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  Delete</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>

    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Isnt there a way to make it more scalable? Like look at the first three columns how they are stretching. I was kind of hoping I could do the same with description column as well

Comment: I dont get you. Can you explain?

Comment: Try stretching the column in jsfiddle you provided. The line that separates html/javascript and css/result.

Notice how there is a lot of unnecessary space wasted for the dates but a lot of room for description. Even if you change the pixels to 200 or 300 it is still only depends on the size of you screen. I was kind of hoping for a universal solution independent from the screen size.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15585/ , I changed sizes to %, and resizing it now works.

Comment: That is the same exact thing I described that I tried in my question and wasn't satisfied because the buttons stack on each other :D

Comment: See, if you have width percentage wise, as the screen size changes, td width will also change, and its content will try to adjust in td.If you want buttons of fixed size, either make it fixed width, or change the width via code on window resize.

Answer (score 0):

Just give an exact width in pixels to the table cell that contains the buttons, so that it will have enough space for them.